# Does web service implemented through jax ws is multi threaded

Tags: multithreading, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have written a web service using spring, cxf and jax ws implementation and I have a basic question on WS. How does a Web Service endpoint handles concurrent requests? Does it creates a new thread for each and every request similar to a servlet or it ia a single threaded model? As we are expecting a huge volume for each web service, Does it makes any difference to slipt WSDL to multiple WSDLs to have different end points?

Answer (score 3):

The web service is, of course, hosted by a web server (like Glassfish for example), which is multithreaded when receiving multiple simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of both your client and your service, there's no such thing as "multithreading".  Your client invokes a request, and gets a response (possibly a fault response).  Your server receives a request, and services that request.  Period.

How the request is dispatched is an implementation detail.

And the WSDL is simply a "contract".  The service "publishes" what operations it supports and what data types it uses with the WSDL; the client packs and unpacks his request and response SOAP messages accordingly.  But a WSDL plays no direct role in any given web service invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mentioned that server receiver request and returns response. What role does a end point plays here for serving response. How does it handles concurrent request.

Comment: The situation with a web service endpoint is exactly the same as with a JSP servlet ... or any other web request/response.  From the perspective of your service, you don't know or care if the listener dispatches your request to a new thread, a new process or an entirely new JVM.  Or if it just blocks.  From your perspective, there is no "multithreading".  From the *server's* perspective, however: yes - it probably creates a new thread.  The specifics will vary from server to server (Tomcat vs JBoss vs WebSphere vs WebLogic, for example - they might all implement their dispatchers differently).

Comment: @paulsm4 I would appreciate if can you share a reference link to support the info you shared here. .i have been looking for something that shows the web service life cycle (like you can easily find stateless session bean lifecycle in Oracle JEE5 tutorial) but couldn't find any...

Answer (score 0):

Its late but might help.

Endpoint.publish(Url, ServiceImplObj) publishes a webservice at a given url. The no. of threads assigned for request handling truly is under control of the jvm because this is a light weight deployment which is handled by jvm itself.

For better clarification you can print the current thread name at service side and you can see that the service threads are being assigned from a thread pool which is managed by jvm.

```
[pool-1-thread-1]: Response[57]:
[pool-1-thread-5]: Response[58]:
[pool-1-thread-4]: Response[59]:
[pool-1-thread-3]: Response[60]:
[pool-1-thread-6]: Response[61]:
[pool-1-thread-6]: Response[62]:
```

This i tried on jdk 1.6.0_35.

> xjc -version
>      xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6"
>      JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB
>      2.1.10 in JDK 6)